# How can I classify a string with a partial string and make a boolean column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, boolean

Say I have the 1st dataframe with the following strings

```
a
abcd
dabcd
qwerty
oppoupou
```

Then I have a 2nd dataframe with the following substrings

```
column
abc
qw
qaz
```

I've been looking for a code that can classify the 1st dataframe and check each row with all the elements in the 2nd dataframe with a true or false solution. For example, for the first element, `abcd` it gets checked by the 2nd dataframe and it contains `abc` so `abcd` is true. Then the second element is also true because it contains `abc`. And the third element is true because it contains `qw`. Etc.

Then there would be this column with the 1st dataframe that would return: `true, true, true, false`

I found this code, but this only covers only the individual elements and not whole dataframes

```
df["b"] = df["a"].str.contains("abc")
```

Any suggestions for coding 2 different string dataframes for boolean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need join values of column `col` in second DataFrame by `|` for regex `OR`:

```
df["b"] = df["a"].str.contains('|'.join(df2['column']))
print (df)
          a      b
0      abcd   True
1     dabcd   True
2    qwerty   True
3  oppoupou  False
```